# My Hexo blog failed build on github pages

Tags: github-pages, blogs, hexo

I build the hexo blog for some days. But when I update some posts today, it runs well locally. But failed to build on github pages.Github warns me `Some checks were not successful`. It fails in
`pages build and deployment / build (dynamic)`, and the error message is:

```
Configuration file: /github/workspace/./_config.yml
             Theme: next
github-pages 228 | Error:  The next theme could not be found.
```

I have downloaded next theme in the directory /themes. Why did this happen?

I have tried to rename the next folder, but it didn't work. I run `hexo clean` and then `hexo d -g` to redeploy, still fail.